# Use 2checkout Payment for recurring payments in Magento

Tags: magento, recurring-billing, 2checkout

I am working on a website, where there are three types of monthly subscriptions.

For subscription, I need recurring payments.

Client wants to use 2checkout for payments, but in Magento when recurring product is added to cart, only Paypal is allowed as payment method.

No other payment method is visible in that case in Magento.

Please help me, how can I use 2checkout payment method for recurring payments in Magento.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time Magento's recurring sales are locked down to only use the Paypal Express checkout. You will not be able to use 2Checkout, or any other payment method other than Paypal to do recurring products through Magento.

Magento's documentation discusses that here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles